# Dynamically import class by name for static access

Tags: python, class, import

I am generating class names dynamically and then want to import that class by its name to access a static method.

This is the class to import in "the_module.py":

```
class ToImport(object):

    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls, parameter):
        print parameter
```

According to a [Blog post](http://www.bensnider.com/?p=20) this is as far as I came:

```
theModule = __import__("the_module")
toImport = getattr(theModule, "ToImport")
toImport.initialize("parameter")
```

But the blog example seems to be incomplete as it gives me a module object without my desired class `ToImport`. Looking at the `__import__()` [documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__) shows me that there are more optional attributes to the function. I succeeded with

```
theModule = __import__("the_module", globals(), locals(), ["ToImport"])
```

Why do I have to give the `fromlist` attribute? Can't I import all the modules attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done exactly what you did and I retrieved the class.

```
In [1]: theModule = __import__("the_module")

In [2]: toImport = getattr(theModule, "ToImport")

In [3]: toImport.initialize("parameter")
parameter
```

I am using Python 2.6.4. Could you explain further, what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Works for me as well, tested on Python 2.6.2 (Ubuntu) and Python 2.5.1 (Mac)