# Django - importing dynamically

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a dynamic import of a python module in django.  I have two different apps that I want to import from, and I want to replace these import statements:

```
from app1.forms import App1ProfileForm
from app2.forms import App2ProfileForm
```

I am dynamically able to create the strings App1ProfileForm and App2ProfileForm and then instantiate them like so:

```
globals()[form]()
```

I tried following some of the instructions in this post: [Dynamically import class by name for static access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939622/dynamically-import-class-by-name-for-static-access)

and so I tried doing this:

```
theModule = __import__("app1.forms.App1ProfileForm")
```

but I'm getting an error that says No module named App1ProfileForm

EDIT:::
Ok I tried this code:

```
 theModule = __import__("app1")
    print theModule
    theClass = getattr(theModule,'forms')
    print theClass
    theForm = getattr(theClass,'App1ProfileForm')
    print theForm
    theForm.initialize()
```

but I get an error that type object 'App1ProfileForm' has no attribute 'initialize'

Comment: `theForm` is a class. I guess you want to instantiate it, not use it. Try something like `theForm().initialize()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Here's how to do it:

```
    theModule = __import__(module_name+".forms") # for some reason need the .forms part
    theClass = getattr(theModule,'forms')
    theForm = getattr(theClass,form_name)
```

then to initialize:

```
theForm() or theForm(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to do this. Imports are done when the relevant code is first executed - in the case of module-level imports, it's when the module itself is imported. If you're depending on something in the request, or some other run-time element, to determine what class you want, then this will not work.

Instead, just import them both, and get the code to choose which one you need:

```
from app1.forms import App1ProfileForm
from app2.forms import App2ProfileForm

forms = {'app1': App1ProfileForm,
         'app2': App2ProfileForm}
relevant_form = forms[whatever_the_dependent_value_is]
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the app more reusable.  If I try and use this app in another project I'll have to change the imports.  Isn't resusability something to aim for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know how you're generting the string to import. I'll assume you generate the whole "path". Try this:

```
def import_from_strings(paths):
  ret = []
  for path in paths:
    module_name, class_name = path.rsplit('.', 1)
    module = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [class_name], -1)
    ret.append(getattr(module, class_name))
  return ret
```

Comment: It's the function's argument. No?
I've tested with import_from_strings(['readline.get_history_length', 'readline.get_line_buffer'])

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you trying to import a class, and not a module ? I'm not an expert, but I think you must import the module using __import__, then select it's App1ProfileForm class with something like yourmodule.App1ProfileForm